# The writing and reading the same file is not working in android application

Tags: android, string, text-files, filereader, filewriter

I want to write a string to the file *abc.txt* and later read the same and compare with the input string. But it is not working as desired.
When I do the same by creating a project in netbeans, it works like a charm but here it doesnot.
Code for Writing :

```
try{
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("abc.txt"));
        writer.write("12345");
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Code for Reading :

```
String ownerPass= null;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    try{

        FileReader fr=new FileReader("abc.txt");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        int i;
        while((i=br.read())!=-1){


            s.append((char)i);
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
        ownerPass = s.toString();

    }catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The case is same whether I compare *s* or *ownerPass*

I don't understand whether it is unable to write file or read file.
Also please tell me how to check the file abc.txt manually in computer.

This is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="NORIS"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2909);
        } else {
        // continue with your code
        }
        } else {
        // continue with your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 2909: {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("Permission", "Granted");
        } else {
        Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
        }
        return;
        }
        }
        }
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".userBase" />
    <activity android:name=".ownerBase" />
    <activity android:name=".ownerPage" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
    <activity android:name=".ownerBrowse" />
    <activity android:name=".ownerEdit"></activity>
</application>
```

This is my java launcher activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



SharedPreferences prefs = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.srijankumar.myapp1", MODE_PRIVATE);


    Button btnUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUser);
    btnUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callUserBase();
        }

    });

    Button btnOwner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOwner);
    btnOwner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callOwnerBase();
        }
    });


    BufferedWriter writer = null;

    try{
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("abc.txt"));
        writer.write("12345");
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


private void callOwnerBase() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ownerBase.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void callUserBase() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,userBase.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Comment: how exactly it is not working? Do you get exceptions? Or content does not match? or what?

Comment: when I compare the string "12345" with my input which I give through EditText , it doesn't match. @VladMatvienko

Comment: ok, have you tried checking, what it compares to?

Comment: Yeah ..! earlier it worked when I didn't write to a file ..but when I compare by reading a file content it is not happening the same

Comment: then what is in the file?

Comment: how can I check the file ? is there anyway ? @VladMatvienko

Comment: watch in the code using debugger what you compare to.

Answer (score -1):

have you added manifest permissions and run time permissions?

add this lines in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Add this run time permissions in launcher activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2909);
    } else {
        // continue with your code
    }
} else {
    // continue with your code
}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2909: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e("Permission", "Granted");
                } else {
                    Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are these ? Please elaborate, I am new to android.

Comment: this is storage permissions, we have to add compulsory

Comment: when though I am writing to the app data folder.. I have t use this ?

Comment: add permissions java code in main activity and let me know if its working or not?

Comment: this is how my Manifest file looks like .. still not working

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.srijankumar.myapp1">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="NORIS"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2909);
            } else {
            // continue with your code
            }
            } else {
            // continue with your code
            }

Comment: @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case 2909: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e("Permission", "Granted");
            } else {
            Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
            }
            return;
            }
            }
            }

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".userBase" />
        <activity android:name=".ownerBase" />
        <activity android:name=".ownerPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"

Comment: add complete manifest and java file in question(using edit) here not understanding..

Comment: doing wrong edited my answer check it again, run time permissions you have to add in java class only and manifest permissions add before application tag.

Comment: check this link for reference: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-marshmallow-permissions-example/

Comment: can you please edit the launcher activity ,,here I have included the activity

Comment: after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); add run time permissions

Comment: Error:(50, 47) error: ';' expected
Error:(50, 73) error: ';' expected
Error:(50, 74) error: not a statement
Error:(50, 85) error: ';' expected
Error:(50, 105) error: ';' expected

Comment: at the line of     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)

Comment: just google it you will find many samples for this just copy that lines